# VS Code Extension Api: How to trigger Image Preview

Tags: visual-studio-code

There is method *workspace.openTextDocument*, but how could I trigger VS Code's built-in image preview functionality ?

Comment: lease provide more information on your issue. Such things as what you have tried, what has worked and what has not worked along with any scripts and/or error messages. Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question.

Comment: Well, there is little to add; Vs Code explorer displays image files (png,jpeg,etc., likely via what's installed at "C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\image-preview"), and I want to trigger the same via extension Api: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api, however, it seems only TextDocuments are supported yet

Answer (score 0):

You can try to disable some extensions and see if the old preview style back.

For me, this go back after I disable **office viewer** extension, which change the preview style.